# Node and MongoDB communication problem during valiadation and post route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a plain node express webserver that send MongoDB Atlas a post request. I use mongooose.

Before do this there is some express-validators work.

Two API key used in this project. Thats enabled and work. Of course not share here...

I test with Postman.

This code from Node and MongoDB expert.

If i change MongoDB cluster not help.

I got two error:

1. Validation error:  **Invalid inputs passed, please check your data 422**

If I comment out validation got different error:

2. Other error on post route: **Creating place failed, please try again 500**

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const placesRoutes = require('./routes/places-routes');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/places', placesRoutes); // => /api/places...
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});

mongoose
 .connect('xxxx')
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

places-routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');

const placesControllers = require('../controllers/places-controllers');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:pid', placesControllers.getPlaceById);

router.get('/user/:uid', placesControllers.getPlacesByUserId);

router.post(
  '/',
  [
    // check('title')
    //   .not()
    //   .isEmpty(),
    // check('description').isLength({ min: 5 }),
    // check('address')
    //   .not()
    //   .isEmpty()
  ],
  placesControllers.createPlace
);

router.patch(
  '/:pid',
  [
    check('title')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check('description').isLength({ min: 5 })
  ],
  placesControllers.updatePlace
);

router.delete('/:pid', placesControllers.deletePlace);

module.exports = router;
```

places-controllers.js

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');
const getCoordsForAddress = require('../util/location');
const Place = require('../models/place');

let DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    id: 'p1',
    title: 'Empire State Building',
    description: 'One of the most famous sky scrapers in the world!',
    location: {
      lat: 40.7484474,
      lng: -73.9871516
    },
    address: '20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001',
    creator: 'u1'
  }
];

const getPlaceById = (req, res, next) => {
  const placeId = req.params.pid; // { pid: 'p1' }

  const place = DUMMY_PLACES.find(p => {
    return p.id === placeId;
  });

  if (!place) {
    throw new HttpError('Could not find a place for the provided id.', 404);
  }

  res.json({ place }); // => { place } => { place: place }
};

// function getPlaceById() { ... }
// const getPlaceById = function() { ... }

const getPlacesByUserId = (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.params.uid;

  const places = DUMMY_PLACES.filter(p => {
    return p.creator === userId;
  });

  if (!places || places.length === 0) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Could not find places for the provided user id.', 404)
    );
  }

  res.json({ places });
};

const createPlace = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422)
    );
  }

  const { title, description, address, creator } = req.body;

  let coordinates;
  try {
    coordinates = await getCoordsForAddress(address);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }

  // const title = req.body.title;
  const createdPlace = new Place({
    title,
    description,
    address,
    location: coordinates,
    image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg',
    creator
  });

  try {
    await createdPlace.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Creating place failed, please try again.',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
  
  res.status(201).json({ place: createdPlace });
};

const updatePlace = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    throw new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422);
  }

  const { title, description } = req.body;
  const placeId = req.params.pid;

  const updatedPlace = { ...DUMMY_PLACES.find(p => p.id === placeId) };
  const placeIndex = DUMMY_PLACES.findIndex(p => p.id === placeId);
  updatedPlace.title = title;
  updatedPlace.description = description;

  DUMMY_PLACES[placeIndex] = updatedPlace;

  res.status(200).json({ place: updatedPlace });
};

const deletePlace = (req, res, next) => {
  const placeId = req.params.pid;
  if (!DUMMY_PLACES.find(p => p.id === placeId)) {
    throw new HttpError('Could not find a place for that id.', 404);
  }
  DUMMY_PLACES = DUMMY_PLACES.filter(p => p.id !== placeId);
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted place.' });
};

exports.getPlaceById = getPlaceById;
exports.getPlacesByUserId = getPlacesByUserId;
exports.createPlace = createPlace;
exports.updatePlace = updatePlace;
exports.deletePlace = deletePlace;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.8",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: My Schema that ask for me somwhere else forum: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const placeSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    location: {
        lat: { type: Number, required: true },
        lng: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
    creator: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema);

Comment: You have required fields in the schema definition - do all of them have valid data while writing to the database?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The database is empty in the the first post request.  That is:  localhost:5000/api/places | Body:raw:JSON | content: { "title:": "Empire State Building", "description": "A very famous building in NY", "address": "20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001", "creator": "u2" }

Comment: Your schema has `image: { type: String, required: true },`; so, where is this part of data? The word "required", means that field is required - its part of validation.

Comment: It is not in place-controllers.js  ?// const title = req.body.title;
  const createdPlace = new Place({
    title,
    description,
    address,
    location: coordinates,
    image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg',
    creator
  });

Comment: It means, the Mongoose schema validation is failing when you are trying to write the data (using Mongoose APIs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238604/discussion-between-milan-nikolics-and-prasad).

Comment: Thank you. and how solve this problem? Why problem it is? I try plain string and other valid URL also. But same result

Comment: I changed all of required: false. But same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a plus ":" sign by title

wrong

```
{
  "title:": "Empire State Building",
  "description": "A very famous building in NY",
  "address": "20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001",
  "creator": "u2"
}
```

and the good:

```
{
  "title": "Empire State Building",
  "description": "A very famous building in NY",
  "address": "20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001",
  "creator": "u2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use this middleware in `app.js`, and remove body-parser.

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

It parses your request and you get all values...

Comment: Do you think this? unfortunately  same result                                                             
const app = express();

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api/places', placesRoutes); // => /api/places.

Comment: The problem happened a post request. | http://localhost:5000/api/places    | Body:raw:JSON | content: {
  "title:": "Empire State Building",
  "description": "A very famous building in NY",
  "address": "20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001",
  "creator": "u2"
}